# How to pass row ID from Flask to Modal?

Tags: javascript, html, flask, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to get this modal working. I have a simple flask web app with a SQLite database and some JavaScript code to add new rows to the table with a modal.

Editing rows until now opened in a new page, which worked fine. Now I would like to edit the row in a modal as well as adding a new row. I'm struggling to get this working because there is an ID to pass by and I don't know how to handle this in the modal.

Here is my HTML file:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="sensors">
     <div><h1>&nbsp;WIRED Sensors</h1>  </div>
{{ table }}
   <body>
      <div class="content_container">
      <table id="table">
         <thead>
            <td width=55px><b>Pin</b></td>
            <td><b>Location</b></td>
            <td width=175px><b>Last Signal</b></td>
            <td><b>Target</b></td>
            <td width=135px><b>Settings</b></td>
         </thead>

         {% for row in rows %}
            <tr>
               <td>{{row["ID"]}}</td>
               <td>{{row["wired_location"]}}</td>
               <td>{{row["wired_connection_state"]}}</td>   
               <td>{{row["wired_target"]}}</td>
               <td>
                  <form onclick="return confirm('Do you really want to delete this sensor?')" action="{{url_for('wired_delete', id=row['ID'])}}" method="post">
                     <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                     <input type="submit" value="" class="button_delete">
                  </form>

                  <form action="{{url_for('wired_edit', id=row['ID'])}}" method="post">
                     <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="EDIT">
                     <input type="submit" value="" class="modal-button button_edit" href="#editmodal">
                  </form>
               </td>
            </tr>
         {% endfor %}
      </table>
      <br>
      <a href="/wired_sensors" class="button_refresh" ></a>
      <button class="modal-button button_add" href="#addmodal">Add Sensor</button>
      <a href="wired_service_restart" class="button_grey" >Restart Service</a>
    </div> 

</div>


<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="addmodal" class="modal">


  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <h2>Add New Sensor</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

<form action = "{{ url_for('wired_addrec') }}" method = "POST">
    <br>
    Pin<br>
    <input class="inputfileid" type = "number" name = "ID" min="1" max="30" /></br>

    Location*<br>
    <input class="inputfile" type = "text" name = "wired_location" required /><br>

    Target <div class="tooltip"><img class="infoicon" src="/static/icons/info-circle_blue.svg">
    <span class="tooltiptext"><iframe src="{{ url_for('targetinfo') }}">
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
    </iframe></span>
    </div> <br>
    <input class="inputfile" placeholder="z.B.: -h 192.168.1.1 -j sequenz" type = "text" name = "wired_target" /><br>  
    <br>    
    <input type = "submit" value = "Add Sensor" class="button_grey"/><br>
    </form>
    <br>
    <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="editmodal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <h2>Edit sensor</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <form action = "{{ url_for('wired_editrec') }}" method = "POST">
         <h2>Edit Sensor</h2>
         Pin<br>
         <input class="inputfileid" type = "number" name = "ID" value = "{{id}}" readonly/></br>
         Location*<br>
         <input class="inputfile" type = "text" name = "wired_location" value = "{{new_wired_location}}" required /><br>
         Target <div class="tooltip"><img class="infoicon" src="/static/icons/info-circle_blue.svg">
         <span class="tooltiptext"><iframe src="{{ url_for('targetinfo') }}">
         <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
         </iframe></span>
         </div> <br>
         <input class="inputfile" type = "text" name = "wired_target" value = "{{new_wired_target}}" /><br> 
         <br>
         <button class="button_grey" onclick="window.location.href='/wired_sensors'">Cancel</button>
         <input type = "submit" value = "Save" class="button_add"/>
      </form>
    <br>
    <br>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Here is the Modal JavaScript code:

```
    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-button");

    // All page modals
    var modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
    for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
     btn[i].onclick = function(e) {
        console.log (this.btn);
        e.preventDefault();
        modal = document.querySelector(e.target.getAttribute("href"));
        modal.style.display = "block";
     }
    }

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
     spans[i].onclick = function() {
        for (var index in modals) {
          if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined') modals[index].style.display = "none";    
        }
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using bootstrap as it makes it easier for programming modals. Please refer to the link below:
[Bootstrap 4 Modals](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_modal.asp)

Comment: I don't want to refer to the Bootstrap 4 Modals, because the flask application is running locally with no connection to the internet. Also, I want it to be customizable and as simple as possible without external linking to sources. The modal itself is working fine, the only thing which is not working is passing the flask value to the modal form.